# Numpy is very slow for basic array operations

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a code where I do a lot of basic arithmetic calculations with a bunch of numerical data that is is multiple arrays. I have realized that in most concievable operations, numpy classes are always slower than the default python ones. Why is this?

For example I have a simple snippet where all I do is just update 1 numpy array element with another one retrieved from another numpy array, or I update it with the mathematical product of 2 other numpy array elements. It should be a basic operation, yet it will always be at least 2-3x slower than if I do it with `list`.

First I thought that it's because I haven't harmonized the data structures and the compiler has to do a lot of unecessary transformations. So then I recoded the whole thing and replaced every `float` with `numpy.float64` and every `list` with `numpy.ndarray`, and the entire data is `numpy.float64` all across the code so that it doesn't have to do any unecessary transformations.

The code is still 2-3 times slower than if I just use `list` and `float`.

For example:

```
    ALPHA       = [[random.uniform(*a_param)    for k in range(l2)] for l in range(l1)]
    COEFF       = [[random.uniform(*c_param)    for k in range(l2)] for l in range(l1)]

    summa=0.0
    for l in range(l1):
        for k in range(l2):
            summa+=COEFF[l][k] * ALPHA[l][k]
```

will always be 2-3x faster than:

```
    ALPHA       = numpy.random.uniform(*a_param, (l1,l2))
    COEFF       = numpy.random.uniform(*c_param, (l1,l2))

    summa=0.0
    for l in range(l1):
        for k in range(l2):
            summa+=COEFF[l][k] * ALPHA[l][k]
```

How is this possible, am I doing something wrong , since numpy is supposed to speed up things.

For the record I am using `Python 3.5.3` and `numpy (1.12.1)`, should I update?

Comment: Without seeing code to replicate your issue, it is very hard to help you. Show us the exact code that you think is slower than a given pure Python equivalent.

Comment: Please show your code, else you are saying *"I've got this code you can't see and can you tell me why it's slower than some other code you can't see?"*.

Comment: okay I added some code for illustration, things like this, but also stuff where I just update 1 element of the a 3rd array with 1 element of a 4th array and so on. Every basic array operation is slower with Numpy.

Comment: Operating with NumPy arrays using loops will always be slow, even slower than using Python lists. However, doing `summa = (ALPHA * COEFF).sum()` with NumPy should be significantly faster. In the cases where you need to use loop-based logic with NumPy arrays, you may consider using Numba for fast JIT-compiled code.

Comment: `COEFF[l][k]` is not the idiomatic way of accessing array elements.  `[l,k]` is better.  It doesn't make much difference in speed, but it indicates that you've only done a superficial read of the numpy docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying a single element of a NumPy array is not expected to be faster than modifying a single element of a Python list.  The speedup from using NumPy comes when you perform "vectorized" operations on entire arrays (or subsets of arrays).  Try assigning the first 10000 elements of a NumPy array to be equal to the first 10000 elements of another, and compare that with using lists.

If your data and/or operations are very small (one or just a few elements), you are probably better off not using NumPy.

Comment: It's not just that but even using a numpy data structure like `float64` is already slower than using simple `float`. I think the way numpy stores data in the memory makes it slower to retrieve than from a simple `list` of `float`s.

Answer (score 0):

I tried two things:

1. Running your two blocks of code. For me, they were about the same speed.
2. Writing a new function that exploits numpy's vectorized math. This is several times faster than the other methods.

Here are my functions:

```
import numpy as np

def with_lists(l1, l2):
    ALPHA = [[random.uniform(0, 1) for k in range(l2)] for l in range(l1)]
    COEFF = [[random.uniform(0, 1) for k in range(l2)] for l in range(l1)]
    summa=0.0
    for l in range(l1):
        for k in range(l2):
            summa+=COEFF[l][k] * ALPHA[l][k]
    return summa

def with_arrays(l1, l2):
    ALPHA = np.random.uniform(size=(l1,l2))
    COEFF = np.random.uniform(size=(l1,l2))
    summa=0.0
    for l in range(l1):
        for k in range(l2):
            summa+=COEFF[l][k] * ALPHA[l][k]
    return summa

def with_ufunc(l1, l2):
    """Avoid the loop completely by exploitng numpy's
    elementwise math."""
    ALPHA = np.random.uniform(size=(l1,l2))
    COEFF = np.random.uniform(size=(l1,l2))
    return np.sum(COEFF * ALPHA)
```

When I compare the speed (I'm using the `%timeit` magic in IPython), I get the following:

```
>>> %timeit with_lists(10, 10)
107 µs ± 4.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

>>> %timeit with_arrays(10, 10)
91.9 µs ± 10.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

>>> %timeit with_ufunc(10, 10)
12.6 µs ± 589 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The third function, without loops, about 10 to 30 times faster on my machine, depending on the values of `l1` and `l2`.